# Reducing the number of row I deal with in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of 2 million rows and when I perform some test to see if a giving command works or not for my data, the process takes like 5 min to end. So I decide to reduce the data to 1000 rows just for my tests, well I would create a dataframe of 1000 rows from the dataframe I already had, but I would to shuffle data to will not be sorted. So I need for example to retrieve from every 20000 rows the 10 first rows.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like:

```
df.sample(0.005)
```

This basically samples the dataframe RANDOMLY and returns a fraction of the data (e.g. 5 rows from each 1000 in this example).

You can also configure it with parameters (See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).